# Tkinter python detecting PgUp/PgDn

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.DrawArea2.bind_all('<End>', self.scrollimage)
elif event.keysym =='End':
```

The above would detect the End key when it's pressed.  What do I use to detect the PgUp and PgDn keys.  I have seen Ppage Npage, PPage, NPage...I have tried those as well as PgUp, PgDn, PageUp, PageDown.  Nothing works.  I want to use the PgUp and PgDn for zoom control on an image.

Comment: The above wouldn't detect anything, because of the stray `elif`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tkinter uses `<Prior>` for <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and `<Next>` for <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

Below is a sample script to demonstrate:

```
from Tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

def click(e):
    print "hi"

root.bind("<Prior>", click) # Bind to PageUp
root.bind("<Next>", click)  # Bind to PageDown

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a [reference](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) listing all of the Tkinter keyboard bindings.

Comment: I had looked at that page and completely missed it.  Thanks.